# Aggregate function for Year and Quarter in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance for the help. I look forward to becoming part of the Stack Overflow community :)

I am just trying to learn SQL for Microsoft SQL Server.

I want to use an aggregate function and group by year and quarter from a column whose data type is DateTime.

I can do it by just quarter as below, or just by year, but not together.

```
select sum(subtotal) As Total_Sales, datepart(quarter, OrderDate) as Total_Quarter

from sales.SalesOrderHeader

group by datepart(quarter, OrderDate)

order by sum(subtotal) desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datepart(year, OrderDate)` as well in `group by` clause:

```
select sum(subtotal) as Total_Sales, 
       datepart(year, OrderDate) as yr,
       datepart(quarter, OrderDate) as Total_Quarter
from sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by datepart(quarter, OrderDate), datepart(year, OrderDate)
order by Total_Sales desc;
```

You can use column `alias` (`Total_Sales`) in `order by` clause.